# Disable pull to refresh in Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

Safari on iOS 15.5 (iPhone 8) seems to have the pull to refresh feature baked into every tab for every web page. This is incredibly annoying, counter-productive and just a bad design choice for all but the most vanilla HTML pages, and even in the latter case I trigger it by mistake 95% of times anyway when using the scroll bar to quickly navigate to the top (ironically no longer making it pull to refresh, either).

One example of why it's a big problem is infinite scroll sites that shows you detailed content in small overlays without navigating you away. The small overlay will let you trigger a refresh immediately upon scrolling up — congratulations, you just lost your place in the underlying page.

Is it possible to get rid of this piece of bad judgement somehow, other than to switch browser?